# SQL select when it is different value

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables and I want to select row from table_2 with different values from row employ in table_1 to show a table with registered complaints without an employing number, I have tried this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM krita_db, sjofor_db WHERE employing_nr != nr ORDER BY id DESC
```

but get then 3 of the same row if the

```
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+
| id | employing_nr |              complaint              |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+
|  1 |          123 | something bad                       |
|  2 |          333 | you have to do something with this  |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+

+----+-----+------+---------+----------+
| id | nr  | navn | adresse |   tlf    |
+----+-----+------+---------+----------+
|  1 | 123 | ola  | ---     | 12345678 |
|  2 | 321 | kari | ---     | 98765432 |
|  3 | 222 | gerd | ---     | 12344321 |
+----+-----+------+---------+----------+
```

I just want to show one of the same complaint and not 3 times, how can I accomplish that?

With my code now I get this table:

```
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| id | employing_nr |              complaint               |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 |          123 | something bad                        |
|  1 |          123 | something bad                        |
|  2 |          333 | you have to do something with this   |
|  2 |          333 | you have to do something with this   |
|  2 |          333 | you have to do something with this   |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------+
```

I want to display this, the complaint with an employing_nr that is not registered:

```
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| id | employing_nr |              complaint               |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------+
|  2 |          333 | you have to do something with this   |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid **implicit joins** in the query.

You can try **[EXIST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp)** operator as below

```
SELECT  * 
FROM krita_db 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM sjofor_db
  WHERE krita_db.employing_nr = sjofor_db.nr)
```

**[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1b4cfb/19)**

Also, you can get same results using Hoàng Đăng's answer (`LEFT JOIN` + `NULL` check)

Comment: `EXISTS` is the right answer.  I would upvote if the first query were removed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff First query and fiddle were for the original question OP asked. Later OP edited the question and updated the expected output. Anyway, I am removing it as it's not answering anything now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * FROM krita_db LEFT JOIN sjofor_db ON employing_nr = nr ORDER BY krita_db.id DESC
```

I assume table with `complaint` is krita_db

Comment: Left join? I don't think that Will help

Comment: It's will list all complaints if it not match the employee_nr  I wrote this base on this expected result cause I did't clearly understand the case he want

Comment: i have updated the post now for better explaining what i'm trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use SELECT DISTINCT instead of SELECT. That will remove all your duplicate rows.